# AbsoluteLayout combined with HorizontalScrollView. Is this usage of A.L. incorrect?

Tags: android, layout

I'm a bit amazed that absolute layout is deprecated. I understand using this is not very flexible and can cause problems with dynamic screen layout. Also I've found alternatives where one uses RelativeLayout and emulate the x & y using margin offsets, but that seems like total bollocks, because it still has fixed x & y values.

Anyhow, what I'm doing ATM is writing a Gallery replacement (because that is deprecated as well), which adds the missing view reuse. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get EcoGallery to behave nicely - scrolling was totally off on a tablet.

The replacement Gallery uses HorizontalScrollView with an AbsoluteLayout inside. Using the scroll position and the width of the HSV it is easy to calculate which child views are visible in the AL (given the fixed child width I'm using).

So the AbsoluteLayout only has those child views that are actually visible and they are positions to match the scroll. It seems to me this is a very valid use case for AbsoluteLayout. Or am I missing something and is this going to break?